# MPMoviePlayerController controls vanish with accessibility

Tags: iphone, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, accessibility, mpmovieplayer

I am trying to get my app to handle the video controls in the same way that the video player in IOS does.

If when playing a video using the IOS built in app the controls remain on screen until the user double taps to toggle them in or out of view.

The user can for as long as the controls remain visible navigate around the controls with ease.

However in my setup although I get the same full screen controls like the native app and can toggle them in and out of view the controls themselves auto fade out of view but the accessibility focal indicators remain. This allows me to navigate around the control with voice over announcing them but if I double tap to select a control it acts as if I just double tapped the video to toggle the controls back into view?

Here is how I display the player.  I cannot find a way to stop the controsl from fading out?

self.player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:fn]];

```
    self.player.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;

    self.player.view.frame = self.movieView.frame;

    [self.movieView addSubview:self.player.view];

    [self.player play];

    self.player.controlStyle =  MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen;
```

Comment: If you need the controls then probably you shouldn't use controlStyleFullScreen. remove that line and your controls will be there.

Comment: no the code is correct, Apple have asked me to file a bug report.